# Saving time with AM/PM in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, time, format

my table has 7 columns,i take time from a jTextField in NetBeans. it shows the current time with AM/PM

```
bno         VARCHAR(45) PK  NN
bdate       DATE            NN
btime       TIME            NN
duedate     DATE            NN
memo        VARCHAR(100)    NN 
vcode       INT         FK  NN      
status      TINYINT         NN
```

what i wanna do is save the time with AM/PM in the btime column, for example 01:30:23 PM. how can I do this? how to write INSERT and UPDATE queries to save and update time?

Comment: This is a database specific question. Which database are you using?

Comment: The TIME data type normally saves with 24h format. You should do that way too. When you gonna present the info to the user on the view (jTextField in this case), you change the format to AM/PM.

Comment: @DiogoSantana The question is tagged under MySQL

Comment: Sry... anyway there is a second comment. Did you understand what i was trying to say?

Comment: hi DiogoSantana, I'm using MySQL :)